# Array have two hashes need second hash key value pair

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I required short approach to finding same response which I am getting from this

```
k = [
  {"child_category"=>{"name"=>"Acrylic Fiber", "id"=>3405}},
  {"child_category"=>{"name"=>"Aramid Fiber", "id"=>3406}}
] 
o = []
m = k.select!{| i| o << i["child_category"]}

o
#=> [{"name"=>"Acrylic Fiber", "id"=>3405}, {"name"=>"Aramid Fiber", "id"=>3406}]
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What do you want to know? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida deI was looking for a short approach to achieve same response.

Comment: What's the purpose of `m`?

Comment: I got it now. This answer from Santhoss is a very short approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

```
k.map {|h| h['child_category']}
# => [{"name"=>"Acrylic Fiber", "id"=>3405}, {"name"=>"Aramid Fiber", "id"=>3406}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
=> hash = [{"child_category"=>{"name"=>"Acrylic Fiber", "id"=>3405}}, {"child_category"=>{"name"=>"Aramid Fiber", "id"=>3406}}] 
=> hash.flat_map(&:values)
=> [{"name"=>"Acrylic Fiber", "id"=>3405}, {"name"=>"Aramid Fiber", "id"=>3406}]
```

Comment: Only if the hash contains no other values.